# Cypress, If else /switch case doesn't work

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to add else if /switch case in my test , but
else if - it goes to only if case, if 'if' fail it doesn't go in else if
it's happen in switch case also.
module.exports.selectEnviroment = function(env) {

```
switch (env) {
case 'alpha':
  cy.get('[role="presentation"]')
    .find('[href="#/company-detail/5bb3765e64f66ca0027e15245"]')
    .click();
  break;
case 'beta':
  cy.get('[role="presentation"]')
    .find('[ng-href="#/company-detail/5bb62c019ee36000273a6e2b"]')
    .eq(0)
    .click();
  break;
```

}

```
 it('Booking should be done using invoice', () => {
    cy.visit(`${blah_URL}#/xyz/`);
    let env = blah.split('.')[1];
    selectEnviroment(env);
```

---

According to environment, it should select the case ,but it doesn't

```
    if (
    cy.get('[role="presentation"]').find('[ng-href="#/company-detail/5bb62c019ee36000273a6e2b"]') ) {
    cy.get('[role="presentation"]')
      .find('[ng-href="#/company-detail/5bb62c019ee36000273a6e2b"]')
      .eq(0)
      .click();
  } //alpha
  else if (cy.get('[role="presentation"]').find('[ng-href="#/company-detail/5bae05a39af4a90027fcdf43"]')) {
    cy.get('[role="presentation"]')
      .find('[ng-href="#/company-detail/5bae05a39af4a90027fcdf43"]')
      .eq(0)
      .click();
  } //QA
  else if (cy.get('[role="presentation"]').find('[ng-href="#/company-detail/5b855022323d37000f48bcdc"]')) {
    cy.get('[role="presentation"]')
      .find('[ng-href="#/company-detail/5b855022323d37000f48bcdc"]')
      .eq(0)
      .click();
  } //Gamma
  else if (cy.get('[role="presentation"]').find('[ng-href="#/company-detail/5bb62ccf5cb043002737d929"]')
  ) {
    cy.get('[role="presentation"]')
      .find('[ng-href="#/company-detail/5bb62ccf5cb043002737d929"]')
      .eq(0)
      .click();
  }

it('flight booking should be done using new credit card', () => {
cy.visit(`${COCKPIT_URL}#/company-list/`);
selectEnviroment();
```

[failure message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hrRx.png)

Answer (score 7):

You are using Cypress commands and expecting them to generate results right away. This is not how Cypress works. Calling a Cypress function is simply a way to ask Cypress to add a command to its list of commands to eventually run.

`.then()` was created with this type of situation in mind. It allows you to add some code to be run directly after the previous command in the chain:

```
cy.get('.myDiv').then(elem => {
    // elem is a jQuery object
    console.log(elem.text());
    if (elem.text() == 'Some text') {
        // do something
    else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I strongly suggest [reading the introduction to Cypress in the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html). It is well-written and easy to read. Cypress is not like other testing frameworks, and a basic understanding of how Cypress works is necessary to write good Cypress code.

Answer (score 0):

it might not be related but for switching between environment, follow below steps


1.  In `Cypress/plugin/index.js`, add below code

```
const envConfig = require('../support/config');

/* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  config.baseUrl = envConfig(config.env.APP_ENV).baseUrl;

  return config;
}
```

2. Under `cypress/support` , create a file called `"config.js"` and add below code

   `const config = {
       prod: {
         baseUrl: 'https://......./data'
       },
       qa: {
         baseUrl: 'https://...../data'
       },
       dev: {
         baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080'
       }
   }

   module.exports =
       typeof Cypress !== 'undefined'
         ? config[Cypress.env('APP_ENV')]
         : env => config[env];`
3. under `cypress/commands`, use this method for login

   `Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {
         cy.visit(Cypress.config('baseUrl'))
         cy.url().then(url => {
           if (
             url.indexOf('authorization.oauth2') !== -1 ||
             url.indexOf('auth-corp-aws') !== -1
           ) {
             cy.get('#username').type(Cypress.env('auth_username'))
             cy.get('#password').type(Cypress.env('auth_password'), { log: false })
             cy.get('.ping-button.normal.allow').click()
             cy.wait(1000)
           }
         })
       })`
4. use this command to run the tests in different environments:

   `"cy:e2e:qa_env": "CYPRESS_APP_ENV=qa cypress run --headed --browser chrome",
          "cy:e2e:dev_env": "CYPRESS_APP_ENV=dev cypress run --headed --browser chrome",
          "cy:e2e:prod_env": "CYPRESS_APP_ENV=prod cypress run --headed --browser chrome",`

Answer (score 0):

```
it('does something different based on the class of the button', () => {
  // RERUN THIS TEST OVER AND OVER AGAIN
  // AND IT WILL SOMETIMES BE TRUE, AND
 // SOMETIMES BE FALSE.

cy.get('button').then(($btn) => {
   if ($btn.hasClass('active')) {
   // do something if it's active
   } else {
   // do something else
   }
 })
})
```

If your element has any random text for example sometime it is `Initiated` & sometimes it is `Completed` then you can do like this:

```
cy.get('.value-text').then($el => {
        // $el is a jQuery object
        console.log($el.text());
        if ($el.text() == 'Initiated') {
 
            cy.get('.edit_status > #cg-icon').click()
        } else {
             // Here You can click on another element.
        }
    })
```